# Cucumber-jvm execute tagged scenario

Tags: java, maven, selenium, tags, cucumber-jvm

I am trying to execute from CLI Cucumber-JVM Maven project by specifying tag.
If tag set on feature level, execution picks correct feature from several and executes. When I try to execute tagged scenario within feature file, execution happens for whole feature file with several scenarios, not tagged scenario.
If I specify in IDE config:

[image: demo]

Run execution from IDE then tagged scenario is executed. If I try to set from CLI as:

> mvn clean test -Dcucumber.options="--tags @retest"

Whole feature file is executed. Below is project structure and TestRunner

[image: demo]
[image: demo]